# How to invoke JSP Page from JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, navigation

How to invoke jsp page from JSF page

Below Code I am trying but unable to redirect to jsp page.

Please guide.

```
<f:view>
    <a4j:keepAlive beanName="homeBB"></a4j:keepAlive>
<div id="successDiv"></div>
<div id="formDiv">
    <form action="/project/Pages/SecondPage.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        name="form1" id="form1">
<table>
.
.
</table>

<a4j:commandLink reRender="subMenuPanel" ajaxSingle="true"
        rendered="#{homeBB.hideNomineeTabFlag}" value="Nominee "
        styleClass="navfont">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{homeBB.subMenuviewId}"
         value="/Pages/SecondPage.jsp" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

even I tried following

```
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like :

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" type="submit" action="#{bean.secondPage}" />
</h:form>
```

In bean class you have to return the secondPage.jsp.

```
public class Bean{
...
public String secondPage()
{
 return "/Pages/SecondPage.jsp"; // this works directly in JSF 2.x
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal submit button exactly like as you would do in a JSP page.

```
<input type="submit" value="Nominee" />
```

Or if you really need it to be a link, submit the form by JS.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit()">Nominee</a>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, I suggest to take a look at Tomahawk's `<t:inputFileUpload>` if the sole reason is that you actually want to upload files by JSF, but don't like the `<rich:fileUpload>`. This way you end up with much cleaner code instead of some ugly JSP boilerplate.